Open multiple tabs in a single browser
Learning playwright and experimenting new tasks. But I'm stuck with a new case as below.

Open a Single browser (Browser1)
Open Two tabs (Tab1,Tab2) on the Browser1
Run two tests in parallel

Test1 in Tab1
Test2 in Tab2



Is this case is possible? If yes - how?
After browser is launched
created new context
assigned page1,page2,page3 for new context.newPage()
But this opens three browsers(B1,B2,B3) and three tabs in each browser
B1-T1,T2,T3
B2-T1,T2,T3
B3-T1,T2,T3
Three test in running like in this series
Test1 in B1,T1
Test2 in B2,T2
Test3 in B3,T3
Thanks in advance...

Each test runs on its own browser context. It's not a good practice to share the same context. No need to.

Why do you want to do this?
